# Can a pass in passbook be updated by an application or only by an APN?

Tags: ios, passbook

If I have an application that creates a pass and the user adds it to the passbook, then is it possible for an application to update the content of that pass at a later time.

i.e. when the app runs can it update the pass with a new time trigger and new content, then when the trigger fires the user would get notified.

Or can an existing pass only be updated by an APN and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why the answer is accepted above as it is incorrect.

An app can update a pass *without* a push notification, providing that it has permission for the passTypeIdentifier and knows the pass serialNumber.

Passes need to be created and signed on a server outside of your app, but once your app receives the new .pkpass bundle, it can update the pass using the replacePassWithPass method of the PKPassLibrary class.

From the document linked above.

> Your app downloads the new pass from your server and uses the
>   replacePassWithPass: method of the PKPassLibrary class to install it.

Comment: because I didn't talk about a push notification at all! :) An APN is the server you use .. an access point.

Comment: I clarified it by saying APN == your server, not a push notification and not an APN in its truest meaning

Comment: Understood APN to be Apple Push Notification. The issue lies with the need to use the certificate to sign the updated pass. If the cert is embedded into your app then it could be accessed by decompiling the .ipa. Only the manifest needs signing so in theory, the .pkpass contents could be constructed by your app, with your server delivering the signature.  Depending on the your pass, it is entirely possible to embed the full .pkpass bundles into your app. At the end of the day, a passbook app is no different than any other app delivering dynamic content, you need a source to deliver updates.

Comment: APN was an ambiguous term.. maybe I got it wrong *right by accident* :D -- anyways, sure in theory an app could produce a signed pass.. it could contain the private key & the certificate -- but thats not realistic since you wouldn't want to ship the private key

Comment: I was looking if there was a way an application can update the pass without interacting with the server, though I didn't explicitly mention this. So will mark this as the accepted answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

only by an apn AFAIK -- it needs to be re-signed so the signature is valid for the new content

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH6-SW1

Edit: as the user PassKit says, of course no PUSH Notification is required to update the Pass BUT
 the APN (here: YOUR access point => YOUR server) has to create the new data of the pass.